# Is it mandatory to create POCO objects for all Indexes I intend to search with ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch.net

I'm starting with ElasticSearch.NET (trying [Nest](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/introduction.html) first).

A very basic question: all the search API methods I see (search, get, etc) require specifying a .NET type.

Isn't there a way to specify an index name so the API infers the response type automatically ? In other words, is it mandatory to create POCO objects for all Indexes we intend to search ? (I understand from the documentation that ElasticSearch can infer a document type from an index by using the structure of the first document...)

Comment: I believe the answer is no with Nest's high level wrapper. Seems this was its whole purpose: to provide a strongly typed wrapper to interact with the database. Using the low level api, though, one does not need to provide a POCO .net target type.

Comment: I have some experience with Nest, from what I remember (I am not next to my computer now) you have to declare a poco class in order to know fields you will get in return from your request. In other words, so the anonymous methods (which Nest uses)  would know which fields to invoke when they are creating the Json. When you declare a request it works with a generic type -**Although** you can use a general one, but I think you can't really determine like this what fields you will get back - if it not so clear, write me here and I will explain better later on(:

Comment: @Green: Thanks for taking the time to drop a line in all my elastic search posts :)

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't there a way to specify an index name so the API infers the response type automatically ?

Not currently. We've previously discussed doing something like this based on index patterns, which would be useful to support covariant responses across multiple indices when types are completely removed in the future.

> In other words, is it mandatory to create POCO objects for all Indexes we intend to search ?

No it's not mandatory. You can specify any type you desire for `TDocument` in `IElasticClient.Search<TDocument>` and the type will be used to

1. determine the type into which to deserialize each `_source` document
2. Provide strongly typed access to document fields through their mapping to POCO properties.

Comment: Thanks for helping. What I did not get from your reply is you say it is not mandatory but I still have to define TDocuments in order to perform the search. Why is this not making mandatory to create POCO objects ? Will not this TDocument be my POCO object to map the document type ?

Comment: It's a generic method, so a type still needs to be provided for `TDocument`, but you don't need to create a specific POCO for this (although I would recommend doing so to work with NEST). You could use e.g. `object` or `dynamic`, or if hooking up `JsonNetSerializer` from `NEST.JsonNetSerializer` package, `JObject`.

Comment: Russ, should you have time, could you please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51494891/1219280)?