# C# elasticsearch infer document types on multiple index queries

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I'm performing my search query on `several indices` and thus I might have several data types in result list.

(I am using **C#**, **.NEST library** for fetching results)
Example:

```cs
var queryResult = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<object>(q => q
                .Query(s => s
                     /// ... some query logic doesn't really matter
                    )
                ).Index("index-name-1,index-name-2,index-name-3")
```

The Result set might be something like this:

```js
[
 {
  "LastName": 0,
  "listType": [1,2,3],
  "Name": "alex"
 },
 {
  "amount": 5,
  "amountType": "usd"
 }
...
]
```

`queryResult.Documents` I'm receiveing all this data as `Dictionary<string,string>` types, but I want to receive them as various *POCO* *(Plain old C# object)* objects according to their *json* types. Basically I need .Nest to **infer** indices of different documents and parse them to according POCO objects.

Is there any way to determine index types via **.Nest** itself or can I use some json parsing library instead like `Newtonsoft.Json`

Comment: Does not seem like its possibled based off the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51121574/is-it-mandatory-to-create-poco-objects-for-all-indexes-i-intend-to-search-with-e

Answer (score 0):

NEST 7.x does not perform any JSON object or index to C# type inference. You can however [use a JSON serializer that also persists type information, so that the serializer may use this information at deserialization to deserialize to the correct type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/custom-serialization.html#_serializing_type_information).